How do I move the input field under the label?
[enter image description here][1]When I wanted to reposition the input under the label rather than beside it, I encountered a challenge due to my limited coding experience. Despite conducting a search on Google for a solution, I was unable to find any suitable answers. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.
html:<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2>Round OFF Calculator<h2>
    <label for="dig">INPUT THE NUMBER</label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a value">
    <button onclick="Math.round">Round Off</button>
</div>

css:*{
margin: 0%;
padding: 0%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2{
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-weight: lighter;
}

button{
background-color: lightskyblue;
padding: 0.3rem;
}

input{
bottom: 100&;
}

This is my desired result in whole:
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/LC9Ykxdr.gif

Please edit your post to include the code you have tried, even though it is not producing your desired result.

I have added the code now

What have you tried yourself? Where is the CSS?

I added the css, sorry

Can someone help me with the rounding off part as well? I have added the desired result as a picture.

@Ashmita Don't edit this question, ask a new one about the rounding.

It is not letting me ask a new question

Just make the label display: block.


.container {
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
<div class="container">
  <h2>Round OFF Calculator</h2>
  <label for="dig">INPUT THE NUMBER</label>
  <span>Enter a value</span>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter a value">
  <button>Round Off</button>
</div>



